# Go to Previously Visited Route in Angular 4 App

Tags: angular, routes

Is there a way to "unwind" the routes that some user has gone through while on my web application? I currently have an Angular 4 app and am working on an `unauthorized` page.

Here's what happens:

- User lands on unauthorized page after receiving a 403 from some network request
- User hits an okay button on said page and is redirected back to the login screen

I was wondering if there was instead a way to go back to the previous page they were on before they visited the unauthorized page. So:

1. Home Page
2. Customer Page
3. Administrator Page (unauthorized)

At this point, they click the `okay` button and are taken back to the Customer Page.

Do I necessarily have to interact with routes? Maybe there is another way?

### Edit

If the route URL is transformed to something like `https://mywebsite/unauthorized`, I'd ideally want to navigate to the route that was hit before entering this state.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use location service, after injecting it into component just use

```
this.location.back()
```

and it will be similar as if you press back in your browser.

Comment: //history object  - using the traditional JS way
 window.history.go(-2);

Comment: Is there a way to go back 2 pages using the above method @Kraken ?